# reducing scaling of tensor contraction

Tags: python, numpy

I want to contract such tensors:
J^{A}_{ir} D^{A}__{js} (D^{C} _ {kr}F^{C}_{ls}+F^{A} _ {kr}D^{C} _ {ls}-D^{C} _ {kr}F _ {AB}D^{C}_{ls})

If I contract J^{A}_ {ir} with D^{A}_ {js} and with the outcome from (), I get scaling like N^{5}.
I can do it smarter contracting first J^{A}_{ir} with D^{A} _ {kr}, D^{A}__{js} with F^{A}_{ls}, and so on to get N^{4} operations.

However, I cannot understand why the first method is faster over second.

This is the implementation of first approach:

```
DF_krls = np.einsum("Ckr,Cls->krls",D_Air,F_Ajs)
DF_krls += np.einsum("Ckr,Cls->krls",F_Air,D_Ajs)
part1 = np.einsum("Ckr,CD->Dkr",D_Air,F_AB)
DF_krls -= np.einsum("Dkr,Dls->krls",part1,D_Ajs)
part1 = np.einsum("Air,Ajs->irjs",J_Air,D_Ajs)
V = np.einsum("irjs,krls->ikjl",part1,DF_krls)
V = np.einsum("ikjl->ij")
```

and second:

```
G_Cls = np.einsum('CD,Dls->Cls',F_AB,D_Ajs)
tmp1 = F_Ajs - G_Cls

JF_ACi_r    = np.einsum('Air,Ckr->ACi',J_Air,F_Air)
JD_ACi_r    = np.einsum('Air,Ckr->ACi',J_Air,D_Air)
DD_ACj_s    = np.einsum('Ajs,Cls->ACj',D_Ajs,D_Ajs)
Dtmp1_ACj_s = np.einsum('Ajs,Cls->ACj',D_Ajs,tmp1)

V_ij = np.einsum('ACi,ACj->ij',JF_ACi_r,DD_ACj_s)
V_ij += np.einsum('ACi,ACj->ij',JD_ACi_r,Dtmp1_ACj_s)
```

where indices i and j indicate dimension 5; r and s indicate 92; A and C indicate 212.

Any idea what I am doing wrong that second way is slower?

Comment: Try passing `optimize=True` or `optimize="optimal"` to `einsum`. Ideally, you can replace everything with only one call to `einsum`.

Comment: Also, you can look at `arr.size` for each of the `einsum` outputs. It could be that the second approach creates larger intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF_krls = np.einsum("Ckr,Cls->krls",D_Air,F_Ajs)   # sums C - 212
DF_krls += np.einsum("Ckr,Cls->krls",F_Air,D_Ajs)  # sums C
part1 = np.einsum("Ckr,CD->Dkr",D_Air,F_AB)        # sums C
DF_krls -= np.einsum("Dkr,Dls->krls",part1,D_Ajs)  # sums D ?
part1 = np.einsum("Air,Ajs->irjs",J_Air,D_Ajs)     # sums A - 212
V = np.einsum("irjs,krls->ikjl",part1,DF_krls)     # sums r and s - 92
V = np.einsum("ikjl->ij")                          # sums kl unknown
```

and

```
G_Cls = np.einsum('CD,Dls->Cls',F_AB,D_Ajs)          # sums D unknown
tmp1 = F_Ajs - G_Cls

JF_ACi_r    = np.einsum('Air,Ckr->ACi',J_Air,F_Air)     # sums r - 92
JD_ACi_r    = np.einsum('Air,Ckr->ACi',J_Air,D_Air)     # sums r
DD_ACj_s    = np.einsum('Ajs,Cls->ACj',D_Ajs,D_Ajs)     # sums s - 92
Dtmp1_ACj_s = np.einsum('Ajs,Cls->ACj',D_Ajs,tmp1)      # sums s

V_ij = np.einsum('ACi,ACj->ij',JF_ACi_r,DD_ACj_s)       # sums A, C 212
V_ij += np.einsum('ACi,ACj->ij',JD_ACi_r,Dtmp1_ACj_s)   # sums A, C
```

There is an `optimize` parameter, that, when given more than 2 arrays, tries to find an optimal order of evaluation - by performing the `dot` sum on the largest dimensions first.  Your `einsums` all use 2 arrays, so that can't help.  But it suggests that performing the reductions on `C` and `A` first reduces the problem size faster than doing the ones on `r` and `s` first.

Look at the docs for `np.einsum_path`.

Comment: @hpauij np.einsum_path it's a very useful tool. Thanks for your answer what was very helpful.